# Observable List em uma list View JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx

Preciso de ajuda com um código, esse código é apenas um exemplo que estou tentando implementar, minha ideia é como se fosse uma tela de vendas onde eu ficaria adicionando na List View produtos para serem cadastrados em uma venda posteriormente, minha ideia é que toda vez que o botão adicionar for executado entre o ID e o Nome na list view na linha de baixo, sem sumir com os outros que ja foram adicionados, porem está retornando nulo. Alguma dica?

//CONTROLADOR

```
public class TelaFXController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtID;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtNome;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Teste> tbvTeste;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Teste, Integer> tbcID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Teste, String> tbcNome;
    @FXML
    private Button btnADD;

    private List<Teste> listaTeste = null;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

    @FXML
    private void btnADD_Click(ActionEvent event) {

        Teste teste = new Teste();

        teste.setID(Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText()));
        teste.setNome(txtNome.getText());

        listaTeste.add(teste);

        atualizarTabela();
    }

    private void atualizarTabela(){
        ObservableList<Teste> obsTeste;
        obsTeste = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listaTeste);

        tbcID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("ID"));
        tbcNome.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("nome"));

        tbvTeste.setItems(obsTeste);
    } 
}
```

//CLASSE

```
public class Teste {

    private int ID;
    private String nome;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está configurando o TableView novamente todas as vezes que chama o método atualizarTabela. Na verdade, se você define uma ObservableList, utilizando o método `setItems` do seu TableView, as mudanças no primeiro refletem no segundo por causa do padrão de projeto Observer.

Então minha sugestão é a seguinte:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    obsTeste = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    tbcID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("ID"));
    tbcNome.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("nome"));

    tbvTeste.setItems(obsTeste);
}

@FXML
private void btnADD_Click(ActionEvent event) {
    Teste teste = new Teste();

    teste.setID(Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText()));
    teste.setNome(txtNome.getText());

    obsTeste.add(teste);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

você não esta instanciando listaTeste, tente listaTeste = new ArrayList<>();